# How can I set outputText to wrap in ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jspx

I have an  component with a long data, I want the field with one row by default and multi rows for long text.

The property "noWrap" true or false didn't work:

```
<af:outputText value="abcd efg hij klmno" id="ot18"/>
```

I expect to see 2 rows without any point and the column (in table) was:

[image]

Comment: Hi Shif, show us what you tried and clearly explain what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I added in the question now

Comment: What version of ADF you are using?

Comment: 11G, Is this what you mean?

Comment: Removed unnecessary parts

Comment: Consider using a read-only input text.

Comment: hey @shif, don't forget to accept the answer that helped you : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

To have the output text wrap when bigger than a certain size add a width inline style property to it :

```
<af:outputText value="abcd efg hij klmno" id="ot18" inlineStyle="width:200px;"/> 
<--Will wrap when bigger than 200px -->
```

Will work for an outputText, for other container element you'll have to use the contentStyle property.